# jQuery on not working on newly added child element

Tags: jquery

I have a couple selects set up, and added a way to add a new set of them. Works fine, except when I run the same "on" function again on the new element, it fires properly, but the child element is not changing.

```
$('body').on('change', '.select-funnel-process', function() {
    var data = {
        account: APP.account,
        type: $('option:selected', this).val()
    } 

    var selectDiv = $(this).parents('.funnel-group').find('.process-details')
    //this doesn't work on the new elements

    $.post(APP.api + 'get/get-data', data, function(res) {
        var json = JSON.parse(res);
        var result = json.result;

        for (var p in result) {
            //this doesn't work on the new elements
            selectDiv.append('<option class="added_option" value="' + p + '">' + p + '</option>').prop('disabled', false)
        }

        selectDiv.select2();    
        //this doesn't work on the new elements            
    });  
})
```

Is there a way to manually bind an event listener to a child element?
Strange that the initial select works on-change, but it's child element won't work.

I think it has something to do with the way I'm setting up `selectDiv`

Here's the html that's added:

```
<div class="wrapper-class"> 
    <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Funnel Step <span class="funnel-step-id"></span></h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="form-inline funnel-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <select class="form-control input-block-level select-funnel-process" name="properties">
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Process</option>
                                <option value="page">Page View</option>
                                <option value="event">Event</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <select class="form-control input-block-level process-details" name="properties" >
                                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Process First</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>


                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Edit: solved**

I was missing the class 'funnel-group' on the new DOM element, so using it as a selector was useless. Added it and it worked

Comment: Have you tested it in chrome console to make sure your selection is working for "this" context. I think you are at the wrong node.

Comment: I have, which is what's making me go nuts. If I stick an alert or console.log into the function right after the 'on' call, it works, but for some reason it won't let me select a child element of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your selector was wrong. Change code to closest.

> var selectDiv =
>   ($(this)).closest('.funnel-group').find('.process-details')

```
$('body').on('change', '.select-funnel-process', function() {
    var data = {
        type: $('option:selected', this).val()
    } 
    var selectDiv = ($(this)).closest('.funnel-group').find('.process-details')
    selectDiv.append('<option class="added_option" value="THOR"> THOR</option>').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3k33vunn/

Also, ensure your selector '.funnel-group' is defined. If it's not, it won't find anything.

Comment: Parents works as well. Maybe I got your question wrong?

Comment: same result. Works great on the elements already there, but when adding new one's it fails to affect the child element.

Comment: Did you want the on method to be added to children as well? Is that what you are getting at?

Comment: I don't think so.. All I want to be able to do is have 'process-details' select element to work. It's supposed to be filled with the results from the post request, and as it sits, I can't access it at all

Comment: Oddly enough, if I go back to basics and use:
var selectDiv = $('.process-details'), it works but changes all the selects at the same time

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3k33vunn/3/

Um still don't understand your question, but you use a hacked way of doing it with a hash for the unique ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114165/discussion-between-david-and-mikes3ds).